# How do I stop an NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

When I press my stop button to stop the timer it just resets to the original time and begins counting down again. I have looked everywhere and all I have found is "invalidate" and it isn't working. I want the time to stop when I hit stop and the label to display the original time. I also turned off automatic counting so I could try releasing and it is giving me an error:

> 0x10e20a5:  movl   16(%edx), %edx      EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10)

```
NSTimer *rockettTimer;
int rocketCount;

@interface FirstViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rocketTimer;

- (IBAction)stopButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize rocketTimer;

-(void) rocketTimerRun{
    rocketCount = rocketCount - 1;
    int minuts = rocketCount / 60;
    int seconds = rocketCount - (minuts * 60);
    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d", minuts, seconds];
    rocketTimer.text = timerOutput;
}

- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender {
    rocketCount = 180;
    rockettTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self    selector:@selector(rocketTimerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (IBAction)stopButton:(id)sender {
    [rockettTimer invalidate];
    //[rockettTimer release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setRocketTimer:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: Are you sure your stopButton is connected to stopButton and not startButton by mistake? Also note that invalidate releases the timer so don't call release and invalidate.

Comment: You might want to look at your code closer, nothing prevents the user from pressing start more than once and and creating multiple timers which you then keep partying on... hence the BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you are pressing the start button multiple times. Every time the startButton function is called it is going to create a new timer and forget about the old one. To prevent this I suggest putting a `[rockettTimer invalidate]` immediately before you create the new timer.

You should also be initializing rockettTimer to nil. Better yet you should make it a member variable of the class because right now you will not be able to have multiple instances of this class.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use another method to initialize your timer. And do it in   viewDidLoad: